# How i can follow reply from command to make new commands work?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

Im trying and testing some script that will install proper version of daemon, but first in the code i want check if its running for real and check the version of the daemon(Then will force download and update it). But im stucked at the beginning.

```
#!/bin/bash

RED='\033[0;91m'
GREEN='\033[1;32m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
NC='\033[0m'`

#Checking Server status
/usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo
if [[ "/usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo" = "error: couldn't connect to server" ]];
then
    echo -e "${GREEN}I will start Evos server then i check for version... ${NC}"
    evosd
    sleep 10s 
else
    echo -e "${GREEN} Server is running i check for the version soon! ${NC}"
    sleep 2s
fi

#Version Checking
/usr/local/bin/evos-cli --version
if [[ "/usr/local/bin/evos-cli --version" = "Evos Core RPC client version v1.1.3.0-2ba4298" ]];
then
    echo -e "${GREEN} Version of wallet is correct! ${NC}"
else
    echo -e "${YELLOW} Version of wallet is Incorrect! ${NC}"
fi

#Checked Status
sleep 3s
echo -e "${YELLOW} Status Checked! ${NC}"
```

There are many commands available on daemon, if server is stopped and you type any command you will receive "error: couldn't connect to server" Thats why i want to trigger `else` option if "error: couldn't connect to server" not happen . Even the server is stopped its triggering `else` command which skip the starting server process and say Server is running. The version checker is also triggering `else` option even the version match with the command provided. The version was triggering to correct version when i used this code (But code is useless because anything there will say correct)

```
/usr/local/bin/evos-cli --version
if [ "/usr/local/bin/evos-cli --version Evos Core RPC client version v1.1.3.0-2ba4298" ]; 
then
    echo -e "${GREEN} Version of wallet is correct! ${NC}"
else
    echo -e "${YELLOW} Version of wallet is Incorrect! ${NC}"
fi

#Checked Status
sleep 3s
echo -e "${YELLOW} Status Checked! ${NC}"
```

`evos-cli getinfo` , or `/usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo` example of how command can be triggered in the terminal.

Tried many variants but i cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test

```
if [[ "/usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo" = "error: couldn't connect to server" ]];
```

you seem to want to compare the *output* of `/usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo` to a string.  What you *probably* want to do in this particular test is to test whether the command was successful or not.

This would be done with

```
if /usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # this worked
else
    # the command failed
fi
```

To compare the output of a command, use a command substitution:

```
if [ "$(/usr/local/bin/evos-cli --version)" = "Evos Core RPC client version v1.1.3.0-2ba4298" ]; then
    # version was the expected string
else
    # we got an unknown version
fi
```

or, if you just want to match the first part of that string, using `bash`,

```
if [[ "$(/usr/local/bin/evos-cli --version)" == "Evos Core RPC client version v1.1.3.0"* ]]; then
    # version was the expected string
else
    # we got an unknown version
fi
```

Comment: `#Version Checking
/usr/local/bin/evos-cli --version
if [ "$(/usr/local/bin/evos-cli --version)" = "Evos Core RPC client version v1.1.3.0-2ba4298" ]; then
    echo -e "${GREEN} Version of wallet is correct! ${NC}"
else
    echo -e "${YELLOW} Version of wallet is Incorrect! ${NC}"
 fi`
This works perfectly! When i put another number it says incorrect now.

Comment: But this did not worked

`/usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo`
`if /usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo >/dev/null 2>&1; then`
   ` echo -e "${GREEN}I will start Evos server then i check for version... ${NC}"`
 `   evosd`
    `sleep 10s `
else
    echo -e "${GREEN} Server is running i check for the version soon! ${NC}"
    sleep 2s
    fi`

Its forcing the start even daemon is online.. I tried

Comment: @RasmonT Why do you call `/usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo` before the `if` statement? The `if` statement calls it.

Comment: @Kusalanada 

I try it right now... and im not able to paste code here in the comments normally do not know how to do it ..

Comment: @RasmonT Comments have _very_ limited formatting.

Comment: `if /usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo >/dev/null 2>&1; then` 
`echo -e "${GREEN}I will start Evos server then i check for version... ${NC}"`
   `evosd`  .... It will still force start (removed `/usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo`) above the code

Comment: @RasmonT Ah, notice that in my answer (and in your new code), the test will be _true_ if the service is started, and _false_ if not.  In your old code, you assumed that the test would be true if the service was _not_ started.  You will have to swap the two branches of the `if` statement around, or use `if ! /usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo >/dev/null 2>&1; then` (with an `!` added with spaces around before the command).

Comment: You are the god! `if ! /usr/local/bin/evos-cli getinfo >/dev/null 2>&1; then` finally! When server is stopped it will run it ... when its running it will continue to checking of version immidietly! Thank you !